# Issue with ExtJs 5 charts

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am new to ExtJS 5. When i was workinh with ExtJs chart.
    I am getting following exception at client side

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - .....widget/category.js
categor...3193905
Error: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: widget.category

I have tried using 
Ext.require([
             'Ext.chart.*'
            ]);
But its not working for me.

Please suggest something to get rid of this.
```

Answer (score 4):

with SenchaCmd one can add it to the packages repository, within the project directory (that's where is is actually looking for, when requiring the package). I'd wonder how to properly reference the one from /ext directory with the app.json file:

```
cp -R ext/packages/sencha-charts ./packages/sencha-charts
cd ./packages/sencha-charts
sencha package build
```

the application's app.json must have this require added:

```
"requires": ["sencha-charts"]
```

once added, refresh the application (within it's directory):

```
sencha app refresh
```

afterwards it should be included in bootstrap.json - and available.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ext-all-debug.js` inside a script tag for a quick-and-dirty dev environment, you actually need to add another script tag for the charts library.

The file you probably want is `sencha-charts-debug.js` and you can find it in `../ext-5.0.0/packages/sencha-charts/build`

You may have to build it yourself from the `../ext-5.0.0/packages/sencha-charts` directory with:

```
ant build
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are want to use extjs charts use 'ext-charts' or if you want add sencha touch charts

```
    "requires": [
        "ext-charts","sencha-charts"
    ]
```

inside the app.json and run following cmd from your app root terminal

```
sencha app refresh && sencha app build
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using SenchaCmd, or just want to pull in the Chart resources for a test or during early development, you can manually grab the CSS and JS an include it on your page.

The following assumes a "neptune" theme for the css, but "classic" and "crisp" styles will also work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<your path to ext>/packages/sencha-charts/build/neptune/resources/sencha-charts-all-debug.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<your path to ext>/packages/sencha-charts/build/sencha-charts-debug.js"></script>
```